# How to delete the last character of the text?

Tags: string, lua

I have the following code:

```
text = "sometext"
print( string.sub(text, ( #text - 1 )) )
```

I want delete the last character in `text`.

Comment: And what's the problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
text = "sometext" <-- our string
text = text:sub(1, -2)
print(text) <-- gives "sometex"
```

For ❤✱♔"  this i did like this way

```
function deleteLastCharacter(str)
return(str:gsub("[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*$", ""))
end

for _, str in pairs{"❤✱♔" }do
print( deleteLastCharacter(str))
end
```

Comment: @Deduplicator is asking about Unicode combining characters. They are required to follow a non-combining character. So, armed with a list of combining characters, you could backtrack. Or use a library like ICU.

Answer (score 15):

```
text = text:sub(1, -2)
```

The index `-2` in [`string.sub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) means the second character from the last.